# I need to create a multiset on Java

Tags: java, collections, set, multiset, unordered-multiset

I have to create a MultiSet in Java and I'm stuck. I need to have it efficient and without superfluous pointers, one pointer and the value, using the Java Collections. The problem is that I have to use `Set<Element<E>>` that is not a clean solution, also I didn't know how use an iterator with this solution. A first solution was using a class `Element<E>` that stores an "item" and a key.

```
private Set<Element<E>> elements;
private int size;
private int numeroModifiche;


private static class Element<E> {
    // la classe element si riferisce ad un'elemento del multiset, essa contiene oltre all'oggetto(non modificabile)
    // anche le volte in cui è presente che possono solo incrementare o decrementare di 1
    private final E item;
    private int frequency;

    //viene inizializata con l'item fornito e la frequenta fornita
    public Element(E item, int frequency) {
        if (item == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("item non può essere nullo");
        if (frequency < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La frequenza non può essere negativa");
        this.item = item;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    // aggiungiamo unità
    public boolean addFrequency(int f) {
        // se siamo arrivati al numero massimo di elementi inseribili non possiamo più aggiungere nulla
        if (frequency + f >= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La frequenza supererebbe il limite consentito ");

        // altrimenti aggiungiamo f
        this.frequency += f;
        return true;

    }

    public boolean removeFrequency(int f) {
        // se la differenza porta un numero inferiore allo 0 gli assegniamo 0
        frequency = Math.max(0, frequency - f);
        return frequency != 0;
    }

    // creiamo il metodo hashcode che si occupa solo dell'item cosi da far funzionare i vari contains
    public int hashCode() {
        return item.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object e) {
        if (e == null)
            return false;
        if (!(e instanceof Element))
            return false;
        return item.equals(((Element) e).getItem());
    }

    // otteniamo il valore
    public E getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    // otteniamo il numero di elementi presenti
    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

}
```

this is the actual code

Comment: What is a Multiset? A set that alows for the same elements to be added multiple times? Wouldn't that just be a normal List or Collection?

Comment: I think a multiset also tracks the number of times each item was added, without storing multiple copies.  So more like a map Object -> Integer, where the integer is the count of the number of each object.

Comment: That was your hint btw, please post code if you have a question.

Comment: yes, I have to store the obj and the number of times it's in the multiset

Comment: So based on the code you did eventually post, what is your question?  What goes wrong with the current code, and what did you want instead?  When posting code it's good to post a [mcve] so we can understand what it is you are actually saying.

Comment: FYI: [*multiset*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) page in Wikipedia.

Comment: Is this for schoolwork? If so, you should say so. If this is for real work, both *Google Guava* and *Eclipse Collections* provide implementations of a multiset. So perhaps no need to invent your own.

Comment: If you don't like your current implementation you could take the hint @markspace gave. But you haven't asked a question yet.